# Multiple entries in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have created a dynamic table where the user decides to add or remove rows in it thanks to the push of a button. Now I need to send the data that the user enters into the cells. I made ​​sure to create an array that captures the values​​, but I do not know how to arrange them on multiple rows in the database. 
In fact, now the inclusion in the database is done on one line of the table, and this is not good, I'd like for each row generated by the user in the table, a new row is created in my db and inserted its product. How can you do it?

This is an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><?php 
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
 if ($_POST['button'] == "send") {

  foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $value) {
         print "product key=$key value=$value<br/>";
  } 
  foreach($_POST['seller'] as $key => $value) {
         print "seller key=$key value=$value<br/>";
  }
  foreach($_POST['description'] as $key => $value) {
         print "description key=$key value=$value<br/>";
  } 
  foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $value) {
         print "quantity key=$key value=$value<br/>";
  } 
  foreach($_POST['priece'] as $key => $value) {
         print "priece key=$key value=$value<br/>";
  } 
 } 
} 
<html>
<head>
 <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test319.php" method="post">
 <table>
 <th>Product</th><th>Seller</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Priece</th>
 <?php 
 $i=1;
 for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) { ?>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="product[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="seller[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="description[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="priece[]" /></td>
 </tr><?php 
 } // for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) ?>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="send" name="button />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the insert code on the table of the database:

```
 $query = "
           INSERT INTO workpaper
           SET 
           product='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($product))."',
           seller='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($seller))."',
           description='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($description))."',
           quantity='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($quantity))."',
           priece='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($priece))."'";          
           $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you show us your insertion code so far? Try to use multiple `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Ok i added the insertion code.

Comment: Like I said, just do one insert per array elemtent. Atm, you are inserting everything as a PHP serialized string into one row.
Do some `foreach` on the arrays and `insert` ever single element into it's own row.